# databinder in repeater not showing img

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am using a repeater to display my photographs, and I do not see the pictures. My current line of code to display this is.

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="'<%# String.Format("Photos/thumbs/" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OrgPhotoName")) %>'">
```

The Photos/thumbs points to a folder within the presentation layer of the solution. I was hoping to use a databinder to combine the two and display on the page. Can someone shed a little light. Thanks.

Comment: Can you put this part of the generated HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing this

```
href="'<%# String.Format("Photos/thumbs/" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OrgPhotoName")) %>'"
```

To this

```
href='Photos/thumbs/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OrgPhotoName") %>'
```

I'm sure you realize that you are using an anchor tag and not an image tag ... this has to be clicked for the image to show up (if the url is correct).

Comment: @jpavlov glad it worked for you, would be nice if you could accept the answer :)